# What does Controls in Asp:Panel refers to?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an `Panel`, with `ID="pnlGestionContenu"`:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlGestionContenu">
    <div id="divGestion" style="width:100%;">
        <table style="width: 98%; margin: auto;">
            <tr id="trGestionCDD" style="display:none;">
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCDD" Text="lblCDD" 
                   Font-Size="11px" Font-Bold="true" SkinID="SaisieObligatoire" >
                   </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <select id="cbxCDD" style="width:100%;" onchange="CDD_Changed();">
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

In the code behind, I found

```
pnlGestionContenu.Controls
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: [`Control.Controls` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: So i'm sure that you've already looked at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). What was unclear, can you narrow down your question to something that is more than asking us to quote MSDN? `Controls` returns all child controls of a given container control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `pnlGestionContenu.Controls` you will find all the Server-Side components of this Panel. This means all components with the tag `runat="server"`. (The other option is `runat="client"`)

In your example, in the Controls, you will find the Label `lblCDD`, because that will be rendered on the Server Side. But you will not find the `DIV` 'divGestion', the `TR` `trGestionCDD` nor the `SELECT` (combobox) `cbxCDD`, because they don't have the tag `runat="server"`, so they will be rendered on the Client Side.

Answer (score 1):

It provides access to the collection of control under the control in which you call it from. Note that it will only allow you to access those that are INSIDE the control you call and those that have `runat="server"` tag.

In your example,

```
pnlGestionContenu.Controls
```

you will be able to access this control only

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCDD" Text="lblCDD" 
               Font-Size="11px" Font-Bold="true" SkinID="SaisieObligatoire">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a control(e.g Label, Text box etc) inside your panel `pnlGestionContenu` you can add like this:-

```
Label lbl = new Label() { Text = "Lorem Ipsum" };
pnlGestionContenu.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Comment: This is true, though I'm not sure it answers the question, but well the question is unclear....sooooo